# How to stop Google from using a Javascript loaded greeting from being used as meta desciption

Tags: javascript, search-engine

I have a Javascript greeting that greets new users with a drop down banner like SO has. It only becomes visible after 3 seconds and when the X is clicked it disappears. Since I have not put meta description tags, on every page Google shows that greeting as the meta data. I dont understand why Google is using this seeing as it is not loaded staight away, will this stop happening if i use meta description?

Should I use Meta desciption? On the upside it might help this problem, but then Google wont be able to dynamically fetch data from the site (which happens to be a forum). It so happens that it is doing this anyway and I dont know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a dynamic `<meta>` description then?

Comment: @minitech: And put what in it? The whole page? Could be quite a lot of info!

Comment: Put in whatever you want to appear as the description on the page!

Comment: @minitech: Lets say the text that the searcher entered appears in the 5th answer to the question (on a SO clone). I want that part to appear in the description!

Comment: You should add more info as to how this greeting is begin displayed. Is it printed in the HTML at the moment the page is loaded? Is it hard coded in the JavaScript?

Comment: Ah, I get it. Is your message in a `<div>` that's hidden by default? You'll want to add it dynamically instead.

Comment: @AndréPena: It is hardcoded in the HTML with display:none; After 3 seconds it slidetoggles into view.

Comment: @minitech: Well how can i choose which div to put in, I dont know what the user will enter?!

Comment: @yehuda: I have no idea what you're talking about now. Add the *new user greeting* dynamically.

Comment: @minitech:  why isnt display:none enough? Also Will that mean i wont have to write Meta tags for the info of the page to display? And why isnt

Comment: @yehuda: Search engines don't* pay attention to styles or JavaScript. It's part of the content, which it shouldn't be. (*Google in particular might be smarter than this, but it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @minitech thanks a lot. BTW do SO use meta tags and if not do they rely on google to choose the META desciption

Comment: @yehuda: On questions, no, no `<meta>` description. Yes, they rely on Google. On the homepage, yes, there is a description.

Comment: @minitech: One last thing, can it hurt to put a description on every page and google will override it if they think the content is more relevant?

Comment: @yehuda: I don't know, but it looks like yes, it can hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is the text from your greeting is being added to the page (a wordpress plugin?) on the server side as visible (so it appears even if javascript is disabled), hidden by javascript on pageload, then just being shown after 3 seconds (i.e. it is really there already and as such is the first major text google finds).

Try changing your greeting plugin/code to generate the div containing the greeting message after page-load, or at least to append it to the end of the document (or apply `style="display:none;"` as an inline-style so Google can see it) on the server-side then tweak the js to show it. It would no longer greet visitors with js disabled, but would also allow google to reach your main content without encountering the greeting.

Comment: It is hardcoded in the HTML with display:none; After 3 seconds it slidetoggles into view.

Comment: If display:none is applied via a stylesheet, then google may be ignoring it, if not (i.e. it is already inline) then insert it at the end of the document on the server, and have the js move it to the start just before it shows it.

Comment: thats quite clever, it is already inline code. Thanks for your help! BTW why wont google use the content of my page as description, it prefers to use links and stuff like that instead!

Comment: Does your greetbox contain any <h#> tags? If so it may be assuming that's an important part of your page... but what google 'thinks' of a page is probably worthy of it's own SO subsite ;)

Comment: no just spans and links. What can you tell me about google putting the Site Nav links in the description instead of the page content?

Comment: I know nothing about that, though I'm sure there is a question on SO about it already.

Answer (score 1):

It does this because it's the first readable bit of text found when parsing the DOM. I'm not sure if there is a delay google uses before it saves the page state to its cache but that shouldn't matter. I actually use this 'feature' of google to allow me to manipulate what the site listing says in the search listings. If you want it not to show up just move the code for the message to the bottom of your `<body>s` node list (i.e. put it just before you close the `</body>`).

display:none won't do anything it has to be moved so that it's not in the first few readable lines of text when the DOM node tree is parsed.

Comment: can you explain me 'use this 'feature' of google to allow me to manipulate what the site listing says in the search listings'. Thanks

Comment: yes, for instance. Lets say that I want google to show 'The official website of Acme Inc. The leading provider of widgets and gadgets' for the homepage but The client doesn't want to show this copy on the page but just in the search results. I simply add it in a div as the first node in the body then set it to display:none..

Comment: I do also but remember that meta content must be skillfully written to reflect the page's copy & context or google's algorithm can mark you down. Also remember that many if not most search engines ignore or at least take little notice of what meta tags say and generally favour their own methods of understanding the pages content/context/relevance